# Access Response Data in Success callback

Tags: restkit

Is there any way to access the response data in the success block for a request using the object manager?

```
[objectManager postObject:[User class] path:@"/users" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
  NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

It seems like there should be some way to use the mapping or operation to get this information as maybe NSData or something.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get this info from the RKObjectRequestOperation *operation

```
operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response
operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData
operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

// parse the response---       
 NSDictionary *myDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
  NSLog(@"=======:%@",myDic);
   NSLog(@"MY email============ %@ ",[myDic objectForKey:@"Email"]);      
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: Easy once you know how!